# Formatting Table Results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is probably quite simple - but i'm new to SQL and not sure what functions to use.

I have a table that holds the following data:

```
Costcode        CostDescr
_________________________________
4000            Product 
4001            Other 
4100            Product 
4101            Other 
5000            Product 
5001            Other 
5100            Product 
5101            Other
```

I am trying to get the output to look like this:

```
X Sales         Y Sales          CostDescr       X Purchases       Y Purchases
_______________________________________________________________________________
 4000             4100          Product              5000             5100
 4001             4101          Other                5001             5101
```

How is it possible to create this format from the results?

Comment: Have you tried any queries before asking?

Comment: And what rules for th X and Y columns are there? Begin with 40,41, 50,51?

Comment: Yes I tried a SELECT using CASE WHEN Statement - So if the CostCode is BETWEEN 4000 and 4099 Then Put is in X Sales. I did it for all for all of them - but there are NULL columns so they dont read across.

Comment: @gbn Yes that's the rule system I am trying to use.

Comment: It can be done but it will be fragile and only work if you hardcode rules. I'd much rather suggest dumping the data into CSV and then pulling it into a spreadsheet and do the formatting there.

Comment: CostDescr for values 5000, 5100 is 'Product Purchases'. What happens with this description? Is it ignored in the required output?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thats a good point - I just call it simply Product and Other. In the table the should be just product and other too

Comment: What is the logic between matching Purchases with Sales? You have matched value 4000 with 5000, 4001 with 5001, etc. ...

Comment: The Rule is that if it is in the 4000's then it is a sales - if it is in the 5000's it is Purchase. The next rules is Within the 4000's if it is between 4000 and 4090 then it is X - if it is between 4100 and 4199 then it is Y. and the same for the purchase side too

Comment: You would do yourself a massive favor if you added a new column that explicitly states what "type" it is instead of being forced to figure this out using somewhat arbitrary rules every time you query the data.

Comment: @SeanLange you are right - I added a generic column in my table to help with this in my actual version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this query:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Costcode >= 4000 AND Costcode < 4100 THEN 'X Sales'
         WHEN Costcode >= 4100 AND Costcode < 5000 THEN 'Y Sales'
         WHEN Costcode >= 5000 AND Costcode < 5100 THEN 'X Purchases'
         WHEN Costcode >= 5100 THEN 'Y Purchases'
       END As PivotColumn,
       SUBSTRING(CostDescr, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CostDescr, 1) - 1) AS CostType,
       Costcode
FROM #Sales
```

you get a table-valued expression on to which pivot can be performed. This is the output of the above statement using the sample data you provide:

```
PivotColumn CostType    Costcode
---------------------------------
X Sales     Product     4000
X Sales     Other       4001
Y Sales     Product     4100
Y Sales     Other       4101
X Purchases Product     5000
X Purchases Other       5001
Y Purchases Product     5100
Y Purchases Other       5101
```

Thus, the following query gives the required output:

```
SELECT CostType, [X Sales] AS [X Sales], [Y Sales] AS [Y Sales], 
                 [X Purchases] AS [X Purchases], [Y Purchases] AS [Y Purchases]
FROM 
(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Costcode >= 4000 AND Costcode < 4100 THEN 'X Sales'
        WHEN Costcode >= 4100 AND Costcode < 5000 THEN 'Y Sales'
        WHEN Costcode >= 5000 AND Costcode < 5100 THEN 'X Purchases'
        WHEN Costcode >= 5100 THEN 'Y Purchases'
       END As PivotColumn,
       SUBSTRING(CostDescr, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CostDescr, 1) - 1) AS CostType,
       Costcode       
FROM #Sales) s
PIVOT
(
AVG (Costcode)
FOR PivotColumn IN ( [X Sales], [Y Sales], [X Purchases], [Y Purchases] )
) AS pvt
```

Output:

```
    CostType    X Sales Y Sales X Purchases Y Purchases
   ------------------------------------------------------
    Other       4001    4101    5001        5101
    Product     4000    4100    5000        5100
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks for taking the time to help me. Much appreciated!